# Minimax Algorithm Clarification

Tags: python, minimax

Sorry this may be a bad question, I am trying to implement a minimax algorithm, and I'm confused on how the 'scores' are created. Do I need to make a tree of every possible combination from a state all the way to a win condition, or just one layer, or not at all? EX.

```
X 0 _ #1
0 0 _ #2
X X _ #3
```

Would the states would be `(X1),(X2),(X3)` or `(X2,01,X3),(X1,02,X3),(X3),(X2,03,X1)`? And for scoring it, do I need to factor in depth at all, or am I just determining max/min score from that *ONE* depth?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking about is whether you must traverse the entire tree to evaluate a position. Minimax is used for zero sum games, meaning one side will win and the other will lose (or draw). For a game like Tic Tac Toe it's quite possible to traverse the entire tree, up to the **terminal state**, and give a score:

- `1` for the Max player winning
- `-1` for the Min player winning
- `0` for a draw

For games where traversing the entire tree of all possible moves is too computationally expensive (like chess), you can set a **terminal depth** (say, 3 or 4 ply into the tree) and return the score of that position.

I think you're also asking whether the evaluation needs to take into account it's depth. The answer is no.

You might then be wondering, *if you don't fully traverse the tree, how do you evaluate a position?*

There are different ways, most important is to do something **efficient** (in order to go farther down the tree faster). For chess, sometimes just counting the material (piece) advantage is enough to produce a basic minimax scoring system.

see the chess programming wiki for some nice explanation:
https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Minimax